# Python: Reversing print order from a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am writing some code takes values, the values `number` and `N` as input and prints, the first `N` lines of a multiplication table as below:

```
3 * 4 = 12
2 * 4 = 8
1 * 4 = 4
```

What I'd like to do is reverse said output to look like this:

```
1 * 4 = 4
2 * 4 = 8
3 * 4 = 12
```

The code is here below. I've thought about using slicing such as [:-1] but I'm not sure how to implement it. Assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
number = input("Enter the number for 'number ': ")
N = input("Enter the number for 'N': ")

if number .isdigit() and N.isdigit():
    number = int(number )
    N = int(N)
    while int(N) > 0:
        print('{} * {} = {}'.format(N,number ,N*number))
        N = N - 1
else: 
    print ('Invalid input')
```

Comment: you could do a for loop with `for i in range(N):`

Comment: @Professor_Joykill should be `for i in range(1, N+1)`

Comment: @allouticey this output: [40, 36, 32, 28, 24, 20, 16, 12, 8, 4] is ok ?if yes  i  send you newer solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can let the program count upwards.

```
N = int(N)
i = 1
while int(N) >= i:
    print('{} * {} = {}'.format(N,number ,N*number)) # TODO: adjust formula
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would instead recommend using a for loop with the `range` method as such:

```
for i in range(1, N+1):
    print('{} * {} = {}'.format(i,number ,i*number)
```

Comment: should be `range(1, N+1)`

Comment: I'd use a for loop as well but I'm doing it with a while loop for this particular piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `while` loop like so:

```
int i = 0
while i < N:
    print('{} * {} = {}'.format(i,number ,i*number))
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: (i = i -1) ? do you measn (i = i+1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a list is [::-1] (you missed ':') and you are parsing twice the same number N, but in this case you can do

```
counter = 0
while counter != N:
    print('{} * {} = {}'.format(N,number ,N*number))
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to do it using while loops, perhaps something like the following will work.

```
m = 1
while m <= N:
    #Do stuff with m
    m += 1
```

Although I much suggest using a for loop instead.